# Create a virtual table within a measure. Ignoring the context of rows within a table visulisation

Tags: powerbi, dax

Task: I want to calculate the linear regression (don't worry, you don't need to understand it) of the monthly mileages for a client.

Situation: I have a table containing:

- FUM ID (unique asset identifier)
- Month
- Miles per month extended (interpolated values)

In the summary table visulisation, I have each month and an average of the miles per month.

[Miles in each month table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFavZ.png)

To determine the linear regression, I need:

- A table of all the months and miles for each asset.
- Only values for the selected client.

The formula I'm using to create the virtual table is

```
  SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Vehicle months table',
        "Known[X]", 'Vehicle months table'[Month],
        "Known[Y]", 'Vehicle months table'[Miles per month extended] 
)
```

That code keeps the client selection active while it's creating the table which I good.

Now, I'm trying to have each row of the table have the linear regression value of: 1,354

[Summary table with linear regression calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq8pU.png)

The rows all vary slightly because for each month in the table, the calculation runs keeping the month context. So when the virtual table is created, it only contains a single month and all the mileages.

I've tried using ALL, ALLSELECTED, SELECTEDCOLUMNS with FILTER. But I can't seem to get the values I'm looking for.

[Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqIDa.png)

Comment: Have you had a look at this example? https://xxlbi.com/blog/simple-linear-regression-in-dax/

Comment: Yes I have! :) I'm using that exact formula. You'll see that in my code snipped uses the same column names in the SELECTCOLUMNS segment in the article.